# Calling a method of a super-super class

Tags: typescript, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I'm having trouble accessing a method in a hierarchy when each class contains a method with the same name.

```
class A { 
    constructor(private name: string) { }
    notify() { alert(this.name) }
}

class B extends A { 
    constructor() {
        super("AAA")
    }

    notify() {alert("B") }
}

class C extends B { 
    notify() { alert("C") }

    callA() {
        this.notify(); // this alerts "C"
        super.notify(); // this alerts "B"

        // How to call notify() of the class A so it alerts "AAA"? 
    }
}

new C().callA();
```

Comment: There is no construct that allows you to do this -- but what are you trying to do specifically? You should always be careful when overriding methods.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While I question the design that requires you to do this, you can easily acieve this by getting the original method of `A.prototype` and using `call`:

```
class C extends B { 
    notify() { alert("C") }

    callA() {
        A.prototype.notify.call(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Grandparent method can be reached by climbing prototype chain up:

```
class C extends B { 
    notify() { alert("C") }

    callA() {
        this.notify(); // this alerts "C"
        const grandparentNotify = super.__proto__.notify;
        grandparentNotify.call(this); // this alerts "AAA"
    }
}
```

`__proto__` is used for illustrative purposes, because the proper way to get object prototype is `Object.getPrototypeOf`. Notice that `super.__proto__` chain for grantparent prototype may be different between implementations (e.g. TypeScript and native).

Grandparent method shouldn't be reached, because this indicates design problem; a grandchild shouldn't be aware of grandparent methods. The use of `call` in methods is another sign that class design went wrong.

If there's a need to use a method from another class (it doesn't really matter whether it is grandparent) in extended class, this should be done explicitly, via a [mixin](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html). Since `C` doesn't need all grandparent methods and needs to avoid naming collisions, a method should be assigned directly:

```
interface C {
    grandparentNotify(): void;
}
class C extends B { 
    notify() { alert("C") }

    callA() {
        this.notify(); // this alerts "C"
        this.grandparentNotify(); // this alerts "AAA"
    }
}
C.prototype.grandparentNotify = A.prototype.notify;
```

The interfaces are merged, and `grandparentNotify` is accepted as `C` method by typing system. This way looks raw, but it is idiomatic way to assign a method.

A bit more smoother way that provides some overhead but requires no interface merging is a getter:

```
class C extends B { 
    notify() { alert("C") }

    get grandparentNotify() {
        return A.prototype.notify;
    }

    callA() {
        this.notify(); // this alerts "C"
        this.grandparentNotify(); // this alerts "AAA"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
class X { hey() {}}
class Y extends X { hey(){}}
class Z extends Y {hey(){}}
```

You can invoke `X::hey` from Z like this:

```
Z extends Y {
   sayHey() {
      X.prototype.hey.call(this)
  }
```